# Cloud Function to receive CSV and publish to Realtime Database

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to write a cloud function that receives a csv log from a python server, then posts it to either a Firestore Database collection or a storage bucket. I am a little lost on how to continue. Any suggestions?

Comment: UPDATE: Found the function to publish a CSV to the Google Storage, now looking for the conversion from storage to the Realtime Database

Comment: Could you please clarify why you are using both Google Cloud Storage and Firebase Realtime Database? If the use case behind using Realtime Database is  to store CSV files, wouldn’t it be simpler to store BLOB files in Google Cloud Storage instead? 

Should the use case be for backup, wouldn’t it be simpler to have it stored in Cloud Storage for Firebase instead?
Cloud Storage is strongly consistent. You are guaranteed to be returned the latest copy of an object whenever a write succeeds.

Comment: As you are storing log files, you have much more flexibility in terms of [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-summary/) as you have the flexibility to choose the storage class.

Comment: @YasserKarout I have a need to manipulate the data before I push it to the Realtime Database. I need to append some weather and user data that is not going to be included in the csv.

Comment: I would suggest editing the title and the description so that it reflects your end-goal much clearly. Reading the description, I understood that you just wanted a documentation on how to publish either to Cloud Storage *or* Firebase Realtime Database.  
It seems that instead you want to deploy a Cloud Function for receiving the CSV log, process the data, and then publish it both into Google Cloud Storage and Firebase Realtime Database (please clarify if that’s not the case)..